# How to add a dependency from the main project to the subprojects in gradle/groovy?

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc, multi-project

Given the following project structure:

```
.
├── src
│   └── proto
│       └── ....
├── build/generated/..
│   ...
├── proj1
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
├── proj2
│   └── person-service
│       ├── src
│       │   └──...
│       └── build.gradle
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

and settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'mainProj'

include 'proj1'
include 'proj2'
```

mainProj compiles some Java classes into the build folder, which is included in the build.gradle of mainProj by the `sourceSets`; And they compile fine.

However, the subproject can't reach the generated classes when compiling. Unfortunately the following doesn't work in proj1/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly  project(':mainProj')
}
```

It fails with:

```
...
A problem occurred evaluating project ':proj1'.
> Project with path ':MainProj' could not be found in project ':proj1'.
...
```

Otherwise the subprojects compile/run fine without code of this missing dependency.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The magic of Stackoverflow is whenever I post a question I manage to think about the problem in a way that leads to a solution. That is the case with 80% of my questions.

One of the solutions was to add another submodule into the project:

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'mainProj'

include `shared`
include 'proj1'
include 'proj2'
```

Whatever there is in `./build.gradle` should be moved to `./shared/build.gradle`; The location ( given the subprojects are set up porperly in `settings.gradle` ) shouldn't make a difference. The root `build.gradle` can be left empty in this solution.

After the above is done the following should be a valid dependency:

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly  project(':shared')
}
```

Comment: This is probably a better design for other reasons, but just so you know why the first approach didn't work: when you write `project(':mainProj')`, Gradle looks for a sub-project called `mainProj`. To find the root project, just type `project(':')`.

Comment: I think that's the answer I was looking for!